# How can I check which expo package requires 'NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription' in apple store?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, app-store

I just submitted my first ios app to apple store and the response I got is:

```
We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "XXXXX" 0.0.2 (1). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app‘s code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app‘s Info.plist file should contain a NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. For details, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/requesting_access_to_protected_resources
```

I understand the error, but I'm honestly surprised I got it given that... I do not access the camera at all. Below is a list of my deps - is there any way to check which one of those requires this permission?
In general my app is based on speech to text and text to speech, so I'd expect microphone permissions being the obstacle, but not the camera one...

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^0.17.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "4.2.3",
    "@react-native-voice/voice": "^3.2.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.8.0",
    "async-memoize-one": "^1.1.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "expo": "~46.0.13",
    "expo-asset": "~8.6.1",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.2.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~14.1.0",
    "expo-localization": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "i18n-js": "^4.1.1",
    "memory-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "mobx": "^6.6.2",
    "mobx-persist-store": "^1.1.2",
    "mobx-react": "^7.5.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "p-throttle": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
    "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-xml2js": "^1.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18",
    "twrnc": "^3.4.0",
    "expo-speech": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.5.0",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/memory-cache": "^0.2.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.8",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.34.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.34.0",
    "concurrently": "^7.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^26.8.7",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "husky": "^8.0.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-expo": "^46.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

you should add key-string pairs in Info.plist and it'll fixed the problem:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Photo Library Access Warning</string>
```

**Edit:**

I also ended up having similar problems on different components of my app. Ended up adding all these keys so far (after updating to Xcode8/iOS10):

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Checkout this [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) link for **full list** of property list key references.

**Full List:**

Apple Music:

```
<key>NSAppleMusicUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Bluetooth:

```
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>  
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Calendar:

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Camera:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Contacts:

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

FaceID:

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Health Share:

```
<key>NSHealthShareUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Health Update:

```
<key>NSHealthUpdateUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Home Kit:

```
<key>NSHomeKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location:

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location (Always):

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Location (When in use):

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Microphone:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Motion (Accelerometer):

```
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

NFC (Near-field communication):

```
<key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Photo Library:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Photo Library (Write-only access):

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Reminders:

```
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Siri:

```
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Speech Recognition:

```
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string>My description about why I need this capability</string>
```

Comment: Hey. thanks for your response, but I'm afraid it doesn't answer the question. I have no problem providing those descriptions if they are warranted, but camera access isn't. my problem is that one of my expo libraries is adding camera access without my explicit need for it and I'm wondering which one.